# Can I specify one CPU core while using oProfile?

Tags: linux, powerpc, oprofile

I need to do a performance counter analysis on a 8-core server using oProfile, can oProfile only record events on core 7? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operf` man page does not describe such an option (which would seem like the `--cpu` option of the `perf record` command).

With `operf` you can try the `--separate-cpu / -c` option (*This option categorizes samples by cpu*) with the `--system-wide` option (*This option is for performing a system-wide profile.*), and then provide a `cpu:cpulist` profile specification for `opreport` (*Only consider profiles for the given numbered CPU*).

For example:

```
$ sudo operf --separate-cpu --system-wide
  ... <Ctrl-C or kill -SIGINT>

$ opreport cpu:0
```